# Odd extension of $C^\infty$ function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If we have a $C^\infty$ function on the half line $\{x\geq0\}$ which is zero at the origin, and we extend it by odd symmetry, the result should be $C^{\infty}$ at $0$, right? Clearly the first derivative works. I think we could see the higher derivatives by the finite difference characterization of the derivative. How would you prove it?

Comment: False. Take $f(x) = x^2.$ Your odd extension is $x \cdot |x|.$ Second derivative is $2$ for $x>0,$ but $-2$ for $x<0.$

Answer (score 2):

As Will Jagy said, this is false. If $f$ is an odd function, then $f^{(k)}$ is also odd for every even integer $k$. Hence, $f^{(k)}(0)=0$. This gives a necessary   condition for the odd reflection to be $C^\infty$: all derivatives of even orders vanish at $0$. This condition is also sufficient.

If you do not insist on the extension being odd, then it's possible to extend a $C^\infty$ function on half-line to a $C^\infty$ function on the line, provided that all derivatives have a finite limit at the endpoint. [Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_extension_theorem#Extension_in_a_half_space).